# Schur Multipliers of finitely generated groups

Tags: group-theory

Which abelian groups can be Schur Multiplier's of finitely generated groups?

Comment: I think it is very unlikely that anyone can answer that one! Of course all finitely generated abelian groups can be, but so can some others, such as infinite elementary groups.

Comment: It's likely that all countable abelian groups do. But I don't know if it's done anywhere (even if it's known that every countable abelian group embeds in the center of a f.g. group). A first step would be to do the case of the direct sum of countably copies of $\mathbf{Q}\times\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$, because the latter contains all countable abelian groups. If it's the center of a (perfect?) f.g. group $G$ with trivial Schur multiplier and $A$ is any central subgroup, maybe the double of $G$ over $A$, whose center is $A$, has a trivial Schur multiplier, I don't know if it's too optimistic.